# html, table and spacing issues

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make a html page which has a similiar appearance to windows 8 tiles. However I keep getting stuck on making the most basic thing... tables

I basically want to make a table which covers the entire screen with some spacing between them and a gradient as the background of the table. anyway it seems to me like the code is not listening to what I am saying.

I say I want the height of cells to be a certain value in percent and it just doesn`t do it.
ALso I would like all cells to be of equal size (e.g gradient background is equal) and not dependant on amount of text in them.

Here is a wall of code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

tr {
    width:25%
}

td {
    height:16%
}

#brightgreen_tile {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #17E35F),
        color-stop(0.84, #8CFFB4)
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
}
</style>
</head>


<body  bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzl1</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzl1</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>

        <td align="center">
        <div id="brightgreen_tile">
            <font size="6">shizzle</font> </br> 
        </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you set TR width to 25%?

Comment: Yeah, the `tr` shouldn't have a width set; that's what the columns are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues in html. But the OP's answer is to remove 25% from TR and add height:100% to #brightgreen_tile. It should have been class and not ID.

```
#brightgreen_tile {
    height:100%;    
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left bottom, color-stop(0, #17E35F), color-stop(0.84, #8CFFB4));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #17E35F 0%, #8CFFB4 84%);
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVLgd/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I used Color:red) - I think it is this you want?

```
td {
    height:16%;
    background-color:red;
}
```